# How can I count the number of items listed on a different google sheet based on dates in 2 different cells and if another cell is blank?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a google doc that tracks information about employee training (Example 1). I have another google doc that needs to summarize the information (Example 2) from multiple different sheets which mirror example 1 but for different teams.

Example 1: this sheet is tracking employees start dates, dates they finish training, and if they have quit. (there are multiple different docs all with the same format that I'm pulling from using importrange).

[image: Example 1]

I need a formula that will count the number of employees currently in training. So count if start date is equal to or after today, end date is equal to or less than today, and the quit column is blank.

If the formula worked the way it should, and I was looking at the summary doc on 11/10/2021, it should report 4 people in the "# in Training" column on the table below (Example 2).

[image: Example 2]

I have tried using an ArrayFormula with CountIfs to accomplish this, but it still pulls 0. Here is the formula I've been playing with:

`=ArrayFormula(COUNTIFS('tracker'!$B$2:$B, "<="&TODAY(), 'tracker'!$C$2:$C, ">="&TODAY(), 'tracker'!$D$2:$D,""))`

Comment: `"<="&TODAY()` & `">="&TODAY()` means today. So you can use `=Today()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give a try on below formula-

```
=COUNTIFS(B2:B8,"<=" & DATE(2021,11,10),C2:C8,">=" & DATE(2021,11,10),D2:D8,"")
```

[image]